# What's the action of a tensor field on a scalar field?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

We say that a tangent vector, eats a smooth function and produces a number. This is also intuitively clear. What does a tensor spit out when it eats a smooth function?

I know that a (k,l)-tensor eats k covectors, l vectors and spits out a real number, so perhaps it is meaningless to propose such an action but the definition of a vector is likewise and we do not run into any trouble.

I tried to consider T[f],
$$T[f]=(T^{ij} e_i \otimes e_j) [f], $$
where the $e_i$ are defined in terms of directional derivatives.

I simply couldn't proceed further. How would the tensor product of two vectors act on a function?

The fundamental question I asked was: How would one relate tensors to directional derivatives, as one does vectors?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a vector acts on a covector only. The reason one can define an action on a function is that given a function $f$, it is possible to construct a 1-form $df$ and then define $v(f) = v(df)$. I suppose it is possible to extend to a rank $(0,m)$ tensor as $T(f) = T(df,df,\ldots,df)$, but this, to my understanding, is not standard. You will need to say more about what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @Prahar A standard differential geometric definition of a tangent vector to a manifold $M$ is a linear map $V:C^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb R$.  One then generally constructs tensor spaces on top of these tangent vector spaces, and can progress as you say, but this is not necessary to define the action of a vector on a function.

Comment: Dogac, I've edited your question because in standard practice, a $(k,l)$-tensor eats $k$ *co*vectors and $l$ vectors.